# Why does my HTML table become half it's size when I add 'display: block;' to it's CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS:

```css
.TFtable{
      width:100%; 
      border-collapse:collapse; 
      overflow-y: scroll;
      height: 500px;
      display: block;
    }
    .TFtable td{ 
      padding:7px; 
    }
    /* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
    .TFtable tr{
      background: #242526;
    }
    /*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
    .TFtable tr:nth-child(odd){ 
      background: #242526;
    }
    /*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
    .TFtable tr:nth-child(even){
      background: #343434;
    }
.container--wrap {
      background-color: #000000;
      border-radius: 15px;
      margin: 5px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Please note that my table is inside a container--wrap, which is inside another container--wrap.

My table, inside the container wrap, halfs itself on a desktop screen and there is just a black space on the right of it.

What's happening?

HTML

```html
<div class="container--wrap">
  <table class="TFtable">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

However, when I remove the `display: block;`, the `height:500px;` and `overflow-y: scroll` does nothing.

What's wrong here?

Also: how can I check whether the user is using a mobile screen or not, and make it so the font in the table is smaller if they are?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a 100% width property in each container:

```
.container--wrap {
 background-color: #000000;
 border-radius: 15px;
 margin: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
    }
```

About the mobile screen, you need to use media queries. It's a long topic, so I let you a link to some documentation about it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this still doesn't work -  I appreciate your answer though!